# How to add chart in page header of crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I tried to add a chart in page header of crystal reports but it adds only in report header and report footer only. How to add chart in page header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a chart in the page header, or detail sections; a chart will only function in the report header or footer.

If you require a chart in the page header, create a subreport in the page header, and place the chart within the subreport.