# Using charts within Crystal Reports/Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics, charts, crystal-reports

I'd like to use Crystal Reports on Visual Studio 2008 in order to generate some graphical representations (i.e : Charts). However, when i want to insert a new "Chart" object on my CR Design i find it gray like it's shown below :

[image]

[image]

What am i supposed to do then please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a chart in the page header, or detail sections; 
a chart will only function in the report header or footer.

If you require a chart in the page header, create a subreport in the page header, and place the chart within the subreport.

[How to add chart in page header of crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640969/how-to-add-chart-in-page-header-of-crystal-reports)

Comment: i tried to do the same way you said but i'm still facing the same problem. Whether it's the page or the report, the "Insert Chart" rubric remain gray !

Comment: Have tried to right click on the section of the report istead of using the menu bar?

Comment: Yes i tried that in both sections (The report header & the report footer) and still yet not working.

Comment: Have you tried opening an existing sample report that has a chart in it (like the World Sales Report)? Are you able to edit the chart?

Do you have multiple versions of Crystal Reports on this machine?

Comment: Problem Resolved : I should have first associated my Crystal Report file to my DataBase before even to start Charting. Now it's working. Many thanks .